# Invalid "let us continue this discussion in chat" link?

Tags: feature-request, chat, broken-link

See last comment on question at [Nullptr and checking if a pointer points to a valid object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279715/nullptr-and-checking-if-a-pointer-points-to-a-valid-object#comment14835312_11279715).

It's there but the pointed page has been deleted, shouldn't the link be automatically removed as well?

Comment: It's deleted now - there was nothing additional in chat than the comments on the post. Should the system automatically clear up the auto-generated comments - quite possibly (if it's feasible). Bear in mind that the amount of time that feature gets used is *tiny* though.

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes? There's no more information I'm aware of to enhance the report.

Comment: @JonClements do you mean that the "let's chat" is triggered rarely? Or that the "let's chat" and then "no more comments" scenario happens rarely? I think when the chat room is removed the corresponding comment (the one that created it) should be removed too, it's a matter of storing how the room came to be I guess, so you can backtrack the comment.

Comment: I know the let's chat is rarely triggered (only on long comment threads normally) and then it's rare to have more conversation in the resultant room anyway. I'm not a dev., but since the chat system and main/meta are effectively different systems, I doubt there's a way for the chat system to inform the main system a room has been frozen/deleted, and doubt there's a practical way for the main system to scan those comments and query the chat room status. Unless it's something really easy for the devs to do, you could just flag the comment with "other" and say "this chat room no longer exists."

Comment: @JonClements ah, so community maintenance, as everything else. Thanks, I'll remember that!